# How to implement windowing in Kafka Streams by a defined time window of 5 seconds?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-producer-api, ksqldb

I am trying to implement windowing using Kafka Streams, wherein we are getting a bunch of different transactions in JSON format from a topic. For every transaction ID, there can be multiple commits (Think of it in terms of SQL commits, hence multiple transactions for different transaction IDs). I need to set a window for micro-batching wherein I will consume the data every 5 seconds and the data is stored in a directory based on the transaction IDs.

I would like to know the approach here and what library/function/class should be used for the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windowing in kafka streams in various ways. One example for tumbling window(as in your case)

```
builder.stream("events")
    .groupByKey()
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10)))
    .count()
    .suppress(untilWindowCloses(BufferConfig.unbounded()))
    .toStream()
    .process(FileSink::new);
```

You can find the more details here :
 https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#tumbling-time-windows

Comment: What is the use of "suppress" and "process" here?  I need to group by my json keys and then branch it to different files based on the keys

Comment: .suppress() method to suppress the intermediate results from windows i.e. if you want to get final result only after the window is closed instead of everytime,  While `.process` method is used to invoke any custom processor. In this case, I used FileSink as example.